# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed

Tags: node.js, macos, sharp

I am running into a weird error when i try to run `gatsby develop` inside a newly created gatsby project.

This should not have anything to do with gatsby.js (a static site generator), since I have been getting the same error on different occasions as well.

When I run `gatsby develop` in one of my old projects, this error does not occur.

```
~/Code/hzr (master) » gatsby develop                                           
success compile gatsby files - 0.996s
success load gatsby config - 0.076s
⠋ load plugins
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/hzr/Code/hzr/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/hzr/Code/hzr/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

I also get the same error when I try to start a strapi project:

```
~ » npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart                                                              hzr@badlands
Creating a quickstart project.
Creating a new Strapi application at /Users/hzr/my-project.
Creating files.
Dependencies installed successfully.

Your application was created at /Users/hzr/my-project.

Available commands in your project:

  npm run develop
  Start Strapi in watch mode. (Changes in Strapi project files will trigger a server restart)

  npm run start
  Start Strapi without watch mode.

  npm run build
  Build Strapi admin panel.

  npm run strapi
  Display all available commands.

You can start by doing:

  cd /Users/hzr/my-project
  npm run develop

Running your Strapi application.

> my-project@0.1.0 develop
> strapi develop

Building your admin UI with development configuration...
Admin UI built successfully
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/hzr/my-project/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/hzr/my-project/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this error?

I am on MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.7

Please let me know if you need any further information.

And thank you in advance.

I searched for the error online so far none of the suggested actions have worked.

Un- and reinstalling sharp did not fix the issue.

Un- and reinstalling node did not fix the issue.

Comment: See: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3438.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with version of dependency name sharp.

Update your package.lock.json file or yarn.lock file to use the sharp version  to "0.31.1".

**Here is how to do it.**

**In yarn.lock.json file Replace**

1. sharp "0.31.2" to  sharp "0.31.1"
2. sharp@0.31.2: to sharp@0.31.1

Than

**yarn install**

This solved my issue on mac catalina 10.15

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).