# gatsby-plugin-image macOS Catalina

Tags: python, node.js, npm, macos-catalina, sharp

I realized that Gatsby 5 requires node 18 and up.
I didn't realize that in order to use the gatsby-plugin-image I also need to upgrade my macOS (OSX 10.15 Catalina) to Big Sur or higher!?!?
While trying to run it on my Catalina I am getting the following errors. Just checking if there is any solution to this?

```
success compile gatsby files - 0.473s
success load gatsby config - 0.022s
⠋ load plugins
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/dan/projects/gatsby-recipes/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/dan/projects/gatsby-recipes/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

zsh: killed     npm run develop
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly confirm that under Catalina 10.15 Gatsby 5 is not possible without an OSX upgrade, but I ran into the same problem. Problem already discussed elsewhere, like here: [dyld: lazy symbol binding failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74955617/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed)

For me, the fix to sharp 0.31.1 mentioned there has not helped, the issue remains. See also https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3438

Comment: Thanks. There is no solution but buying a new MAC just for Gatsby Sharp plugin to work